# Question about when the Biot-Savart law holds

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, classical-electrodynamics

Is the condition $\dfrac{\partial\textbf{E}}{dt} = \boldsymbol{0}$ sufficient and necessary for the Biot-Savart law to hold? If it's sufficient but not necessary, under what other conditions does the Biot-Savart law hold? If it's necessary but not sufficient, what else is required for the Biot-Savart law to hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary but not sufficient. For Biot-Savart to hold, you need your current carrying wires to be in infinite free space, such that there is a boundary condition for $\mathbf B$ to fall off to zero at infinity and more or less at the same rate for every direction.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you'd explain in more detail the "more or less at the same rate in every direction" thing.